# Split hierarchical string between two special characters in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I was working with a string like

`$upper('anothervalue')$`

I wrote a parser that parses this statement well with the code below.

But, now another system is sending a complex string like (I can get any number of chained string):

`$upper($trim('somevalue')$)$ - $upper('anothervalue')$`

How can I loop through the hierarchical data in a particular order to evaluate the functions (starting with the innermost match):

`$trim('somevalue')$` --I will evaluate this, store it say in variable `x`

`$upper(x)$` --now evaluate upper with the result from the previous statement

`$upper('anothervalue')$`

```
private static object EvaluateFunctionsInJson(string jsonValue)
{
    object origJsonValue = jsonValue;
    var fnMatches = Regex.Matches(jsonValue.ToString(), @"\$(.+?)\$");
    var fnCount = fnMatches.Count;
    foreach (var fnMatch in fnMatches)
    {
        // call another method to evaluate the function
        object replaceValue = EvaluateFunction(fnMatch.ToString());

        if (fnCount > 1)
        {
            origJsonValue = origJsonValue.ToString().Replace(fnMatch.ToString(), replaceValue.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            origJsonValue = replaceValue;
        }
    }
    return origJsonValue;
}



private static object EvaluateFunction(string jsonValue)
{
    var functionWithoutDollarSign = Regex.Replace(jsonValue.ToString(), @"[$$]+", "");
    string functionName = Regex.Match(functionWithoutDollarSign, @"\b[A-Za-z]+\b", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value; //get the first word
    var functionParam = Regex.Match(functionWithoutDollarSign, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Value; //get the text between paranthesis
    var functionParamWithoutParanthesis = Regex.Replace(functionParam.ToString(), @"[\(\)]+", "");

    var funcParams = functionParamWithoutParanthesis.Split(',');
    var value = funcParams[0];
    switch (functionName.ToLower().Trim())
    {
        case "upper":
            return value.ToUpper();
        case "lower":
            return value.ToLower();
        case "number":
            return Convert.ToInt64(value);
        case "boolean":
            return Convert.ToBoolean(value);
        default:
            return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How complex does this need to get?  You may be able to do this iteratively but it'll be painful and won't scale well.  You could try to do something with recursion, but I think you would be better served using expression trees in this case.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/

Comment: I am not expecting it to be crazy complex. Just two levels - function under function. I never worked with expression trees before, need to explore it - thanks for the link.

Comment: Is this going to be possible? There's no distinction between 'opening dollar' and 'closing dollar' signs, so how are you supposed to distinguish between a dollar sign that starts an expression, and one that ends one? Like, above your more complex expression is 'open, open, close, close, open, close', but how would you know it's not 'open, close, open, close, open close'?

Comment: Further thought: if every 'opening dollar' is succeeded by a known keyword ('upper', 'trim', etc.) I suppose you could first replace all of *those* instances with an opening token and then keyword, and then replace all remaining dollar signs with a closing token, and then you would have known opens and closes...

Comment: I don't understand the need for the closing dollar sign.  Why not just do something like `$upper($trim('somevalue')) - $upper('anothervalue')` where dollar sign signals the start of a "function" and then what comes after the dollar sign is the function name and the argument to the function is enclosed in parenthesis.

Comment: @juharr that's fine too, I thought it would be easier to extract between two know symbols. But, if it's easier to do without, I am fine. But, how am I going to start reading from innermost function?

Comment: @Jonathan, I know it is tricky to identify open/close expressions. The keywords will be a defined list. Not sure how replacing will ease the process of identifying each function.

Comment: I think @juharr has a good point.  Just skip the $.  You can use the parens to push the "methods" onto a data structure.  In this case, since you want FIFO, I think you should use some kind of queue.  Open paren would mean push onto the queue, so first one goes on, then second.  Close paren would mean to consume from the queue, so first one would be read, then the second.  That would give you the proper order you want.  Data structures are your friend.  Leverage them.

Comment: I see standard mathematical expressions. To parse them, use the standard recursive descent parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "$upper($trim('somevalue   ')$)$ - $upper('anothervalue')$";
        var pattern = @"(?s)\$(?<functionName>\w+)\('?(?<value>[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'?\)\$";
        var prev = string.Empty;
        do {
            prev = text;
            text = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, x => {
                switch (x.Groups["functionName"].Value.ToLower().Trim())
                {
                    case "trim":
                        return x.Groups["value"].Value.Trim();
                    case "upper":
                        return x.Groups["value"].Value.ToUpper();
                    case "lower":
                        return x.Groups["value"].Value.ToLower();
                    case "number":
                        return Convert.ToInt64(x.Groups["value"].Value).ToString();
                    case "boolean":
                        return Convert.ToBoolean(x.Groups["value"].Value).ToString();
                    default:
                        return x.Groups["value"].Value;
                }
            });
        } while (prev != text);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

See the [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/cLgIsX).

The regex is

```cs
(?s)\$(?<functionName>\w+)\('?(?<value>[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'?\)\$
```

See the [online regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%5c%24%28%3f%3cfunctionName%3e%5cw%2b%29%5c%28%27%3f%28%3f%3cvalue%3e%5b%5e%27%5c%5c%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%27%5c%5c%5d*%29*%29%27%3f%5c%29%5c%24&i=%24upper%28%24trim%28%27somevalue+++%27%29%24%29%24+-+%24upper%28%27anothervalue%27%29%24). *Details*::

- `(?s)` - a `RegexOptions.Singleline` inline regex option that makes `.` match any chars inlcluding newline
- `\$` - a dollar symbol
- `(?<functionName>\w+)` - Group "functionName": one or more word chars
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `'?` - an optional `'` char
- `(?<value>[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)` - Group "value": zero or more chars other than `'` and `\` and then zero or more occurrences of any escaped char and then zero or more chars other than `'` and `\`
- `'?\)` - `')` or `)` string
- `\$`

The `do {...} while (prev != text)` searches and replaces matches in the `text` variable until no match is found.

Comment: That's one complicated regex. But it works great for multiple functions. Honestly, I am not great at editing regex. How can I make it work for a string like `$upper($append('somevalue', '-updated')$)$` where I handle more than one parameters.  Basically, read anything inside `(` and `)`, I guess. I can have different parameters for different functions, what I am saying.

Comment: @SriReddy Capture the values into "value" group capture collection and then you will be able to access them as a list, see [this proof of concept](https://ideone.com/RJhMPz).

Comment: The proof of concept actually broke the functionality that was working with your previous regex, like processing multiple functions `$trim($upper($lower('anothervalue')$)$)$`. I want to make these work with this logic - `$trim($upper($lower('anothervalue')$)$)$`, `$trim($upper($append('anothervalue', '--new')$)$)$`, `$upper(mark)$`, `$upper($ifempty('', 'unknown')$)$`